# Ruby Generate Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to generate a self-signed certificate in ruby, but am running into trouble.  This is what I currently have right now:

```
require 'openssl'

if ARGV.length != 3 then
    puts "USAGE: #{__FILE__} <type[der|pem]> <private-out> <public-out>"
    exit
end

type = ARGV[0].downcase
privateKeyFile = ARGV[1]
publicKeyFile = ARGV[2]

values = [{ 'C' => 'US'},
          {'ST' => 'SomeState'},
          { 'L' => 'SomeCity'},
          { 'O' => 'Organization'},
          {'OU' => 'Organizational Unit'},
          {'CN' => "somesite.com"}]

name = values.collect{ |l| l.collect { |k, v| "/#{k}=#{v}" }.join }.join

key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(1024)
pub = key.public_key
ca = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse(name)
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
cert.version = 2 
cert.serial = 1 
cert.subject = ca
cert.issuer = ca
cert.public_key = pub 
cert.not_before = Time.now
cert.not_before = Time.now + (360 * 24 * 3600)

File.open(privateKeyFile + "." + type, "w") {|f| f.write key.send("to_#{type}") }
File.open(publicKeyFile + "." + type, "w") {|f| f.write cert.send("to_#{type}") }
```

When I try to use the generated private key and certificate in apache, I get this error:

```
[Thu Mar 04 10:58:44 2010] [error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/ssl/certs/gnarly.pem
[Thu Mar 04 10:58:44 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Thu Mar 04 10:58:44 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

This is what my certificate says:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<lots of stuff>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It calls itself a certificate instead of a CSR, which is what most of the things I've found online say about that apache2 error (that I might have gotten the CSR and CERT mixed up).  My guess is that I'm not generating the right type of certificate. Maybe I have to change the serial or version attributes.  Also, I'm not doing any self-signing anywhere, not that I know of anyways.  I know you can do something like this though:

```
require "openssl"
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(1024)
signature = key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, "data to sign")
```

Reminder: My goal is to generate a self-signed certificate, in case my long-ish question lost focus on the way.

EDIT:  I guess the real question is how to sign a certificate with a key

Comment: Any one who will be interested I prepared csr exammple in ruby, You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/1922961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found several very good sources for examples using OpenSSL:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6309

http://projects.reductivelabs.com/projects/puppet/repository/revisions/master/entry/lib/puppet/sslcertificates.rb

http://projects.reductivelabs.com/projects/puppet/repository/revisions/master/entry/lib/puppet/sslcertificates/ca.rb

http://projects.reductivelabs.com/projects/puppet/repository/revisions/master/entry/lib/puppet/sslcertificates/certificate.rb

I still haven't found any good documentation for this yet, although I don't think it would take too long to write down what's in the examples.

I've also figured out how to do what I wanted from the puppet source code.  Hope this helps someone else who's frustrated at the lack of documentation of OpenSSL in ruby.

Comment: Ah... the transient nature of the web. Less than 2 years later, all the above links are broken.

Comment: The structure of Puppet's source has changed as well but the same general information can be gleaned from their GitHub repo: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/tree/master/lib/puppet/ssl

Comment: All the links are broken

Answer (score 9):

I created a helper class for this from code I lifted directly from [nickyp's gist](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2F886884&ei=rkj1U-jjB4OYyATppIKACg&usg=AFQjCNEVkUYUq0qAjSwZCmlseRe2xH1kzw&sig2=I6Ta9Ub9oZP_EYtGMGBL_w) that I found on a Google search.  The only dependency you need is the openssl gem (`gem install openssl`)

```
require 'openssl'

class SelfSignedCertificate
  def initialize
    @key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(1024)
    public_key = @key.public_key

    subject = "/C=BE/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=Test"

    @cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
    @cert.subject = @cert.issuer = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse(subject)
    @cert.not_before = Time.now
    @cert.not_after = Time.now + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
    @cert.public_key = public_key
    @cert.serial = 0x0
    @cert.version = 2

    ef = OpenSSL::X509::ExtensionFactory.new
    ef.subject_certificate = @cert
    ef.issuer_certificate = @cert
    @cert.extensions = [
        ef.create_extension("basicConstraints","CA:TRUE", true),
        ef.create_extension("subjectKeyIdentifier", "hash"),
    # ef.create_extension("keyUsage", "cRLSign,keyCertSign", true),
    ]
    @cert.add_extension ef.create_extension("authorityKeyIdentifier",
                                           "keyid:always,issuer:always")

    @cert.sign @key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
  end

  def self_signed_pem
    @cert.to_pem
  end

  def private_key
    @key
  end
end
```

**Usage:**

```
my_cert = SelfSignedCertificate.new
puts "Private Key:\n#{my_cert.private_key}"
puts "Self-signed PEM:\n#{my_cert.self_signed_pem}"
```

**Output:**

```
Private Key:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Signed PEM:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `create_self_signed_cert` method in `webrick/ssl`, which is easy to understand and useful.

Comment: can you please provide a usage example?

Comment: `cert, rsa = WEBrick::Utils.create_self_signed_cert 1024, [["CN", "localhost"]], ""`

Comment: remember `require 'webrick/https'`